# How to Create Categories and Subcategories of Folders (Directories) using PHP and SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite

Im new to php and sqlite. I have a sqlite database that contains the following fields:

```
name
voterID,
memberID,
constituency,
electoralarea,
branchcode
```

I'm able to display the output in html. What I want to do now is to create a directory for the content (tree) and should follow in this order:

Constituency,
electoralarea,
branchcode,

The branchcode should contain a pdf file of the content. That is name, voterID, memberID, photo in a table format

This is how my code looks like:

```
<?php
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
  function __construct()
  {
     $this->open('C:\xampp\htdocs\NDC\database\central.NDC');

  }
}
$db = new MyDB();
if(!$db){
  echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
 } 
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<title>SUPPLEMENTARY LIST</title>

</style
</head> 

<body>

  <?php

$sql =<<<EOF
select         v.pollingName,v.name,v.memberID,p.foto,v.voterID,v.branchCode,v.electoralName    ,v.constituency
from voter v,photo p
where v.voterID = p.voterID and v.branchCode IN ('B152704') order by         v.name,v.voterID;
group by v.branchcode
EOF;

echo "<table border='1' align ='center' cellpadding ='1' cellspacing     ='0' width=800 height=100>

<tr>
<th><font face='Arial' size = 2.5>#</font></th>
<th><font face='Arial' size = 2.5>FULLNAME</font></th>
<th><font face='Arial' size = 2.5>MEMBERID</font></th>
<th><font face='Arial' size = 2.5>VOTERID</font></th>
<th><font face='Arial' size = 2.5>BRANCHCODE</font></th>
<th><font face='Arial' size = 2.5>PICTURE</font></th>
<th><font face='Arial' size = 2.5>Status (Tick)</font></th>
</tr>";
$counter = 0;
/*$image = imagecreatefromstring($blob);
ob_start(); //You could also just output the $image via header() and         bypass this buffer capture.
imagejpeg($image, null, 80)
$foto = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();*/

   $ret = $db->query($sql);
 $i = 0;
 echo '<tbody><tr>';
   while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
 if ($i > 1 && $i % 10 == 0) 
        echo '</tr><tr class="breakAfter">'; 
    else if ($i)  
      echo '</tr><tr>'; 
    ++$i;

    $counter++;
    //echo "<center><strong>".$row ['electoralName'];
   // echo "<font face='Arial' size = 2.5 >" .     wordwrap($row['pollingName'],-1,"<br />\n"). "</font>";
      echo "<tr>";

echo "<td align = 'center'><font face='Arial' size = 2.5 ><strong>" . $counter . "</strong></font></td>";
echo "<td align = 'center'><font face='Arial' size = 2.5 >" . wordwrap($row['name'],40, "<br />\n") . "</font></td>";
echo "<td align = 'center'><font face='Arial' size = 2.5 >" . $row['memberID'] . "</font></td>";
 echo "<td align = 'center'><font face='Arial' size = 2.5 >" .         $row['voterID'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td align = 'center'><font face='Arial' size = 2.5 >" .         $row['branchCode'] . "</font></td>";
    //echo "<td align = 'center'><font face='verdana'>" . $row[''] .     "</font>    </td>";
  echo "<td align = 'center'>" . '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'     .     base64_encode($row['foto']).'"  width="100" height="115"/>' . "</td>";
            //'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' .         base64_encode($row2['image']) . '" width="290" height="290">' 

    echo "<td align = 'center'><strong>" . '['.'&nbsp; '.'&nbsp;     '.'&nbsp;     '.']'. "</strong></td>";
    //echo "<p style=\"page-break-after: always\">\n";
    echo "</tr>";

    //'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image']     ).'"/>'
   }

   //echo "Operation done successfully\n";
   $db->close();
?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use is_dir() and mkdir() functions to check and create directory.